# Encapsulating member variables of a raw C# class that was marked as serializable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encapsulation, mvp, serializable

I have a raw C# class that is marked as `[Serializable]`. The fields are all public since the object is being saved to a file with Newtonsoft JSON.NET.

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerGlobalAggregateData
{
    public int timesPlayed;
    public int timesCleared;
    public int timesFailed;

    public PlayerGlobalAggregateData(int timesPlayed = default,
                                     int timesCleared = default,
                                     int timesFailed = default)
    {
        this.timesPlayed = timesPlayed;
        this.timesCleared = timesCleared;
        this.timesFailed = timesFailed;
    }
}
```

Now I have a scriptable object in which I have this class instance as a member variable:

```
public class PlayerGlobalAggregateModel : ScriptableObject
{
    private PlayerGlobalAggregateData _data;

    public void SetModelData(PlayerGlobalAggregateData data)
    {
        _data = data;
        //TestCoroutine();
    }

    public PlayerGlobalAggregateData GetPlayerAggregateData()
    {
        //TestCoroutine();
        return _data;
    }
}
```

The idea behind doing things like this is that I load all the data from the file into the member variable `_data` using the method `SetModelData();` method. And throughout the game, I modify the model and when saving back to the file I use `GetPlayerAggregateData()`.

Now the thing that is troubling me is that any class that has this scriptable object as a reference can access all the data in the `_data` field and even modify it since the fields are all public in the `PlayerGlobalAggregateData` class.

How can I encapsulate those fields better?

I am not able to figure out how to go about this.

Comment: _"And throughout the game i modify the model"_ - how do you plan to modify the data?

Comment: I have a Method 
    public void UpdateTimesPCFData(LevelId levelId,  LevelResult levelResult, DifficultyType difficultyType)
In the method i do something like this. _data.timesPlayed += 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the fields as private and decorate with appropriate attributes, eg.

```
[SerializeField][JsonProperty] private int someDataField;
```

Then expose a getter property for each variable that should be accessible externally, eg.

```
public int SomeDataField => someDataField;
```

[SerializeFieldAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)
This allows the private field to be serialized and editted in the unity inspector

```
[SerializeField]
```

[JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm)
This allows JSON.Net to serialize the private field

```
[JsonProperty]
```